# Javascript array initialization behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays

// fixed a typo [] should be [[]] // sorry 
// but i remain stumped.
// i want to initialize an empty array with the right number of dimensions and not right number of elements.

I am getting the following behavior.

```
var sdata = [[]];
sdata[0][0] = 4;
sdata[0][1] = 5;
```

it works.

but

```
var sdata = [[]];
sdata[0][0] = 4;
sdata[0][1] = 5;
sdata[1][0] = 6;
```

does not work , meaning the third element.

however

```
var sdata = [[]];
    sdata[0] = [];
    sdata[1] = [];
sdata[0][0] = 4;
sdata[0][1] = 5;
sdata[1][0] = 6;
```

also works.

Which means I cannot just create an empty array and give values to it. I have to count how many rows will it be, and then initialize an empty array of that much length and then give values to its elements. Which is particularly stupid because i don't know the length of data that I am going to get.

And when i say it does not work it means console.log prints vs does not print.

UPDATE : Yes this is stupid. But there is a silver line -- you only have to initialize at the first level. Levels below that become auto-initialized when you give them a value.

so basically, the following will work

```
var sdata = [[]];
sdata[0][0]= 4;  // first element initialization is not a problem
sdata[0][1]= 4;  // still falls under first
```

but following wont

```
var sdata = [[]];
sdata[0][0]= 4;
sdata[0][1]= 4;
sdata[1][0]= 4; // no it wont, anything after first parent element requires explicit initialization
```

so the following will

```
var sdata = [[]];
sdata[0]=[]
sdata[1]=[]     // explicit initialization
sdata[0][0]= 4;
sdata[0][1]= 4;
sdata[1][0]= 4; // now it will
```

however the following will work too

```
var sdata = [[]];
sdata[0]=[]
sdata[1]=[]
sdata[0][0]= 4;
sdata[0][1]= 4;
sdata[1][0]= 4;    // expected to work and will
sdata[1][1]= 4;    // expected to work and will
sdata[1][0][0]=5;  // expected to work since its first element and will
sdata[1][1][1]=5;  // expected not to work since its the second element , but it will work, since parent is initialized
```

bottom line - only first level initializations are required, levels below that is not a problem.

so now i am basically doing

```
for (x=0;x<y;x++)
        { sdata[x] = []; }  
sdata[c][d][e] = 4; // and so forth
```

where i gotta know y beforehand, and luckily i do.

Comment: Are you sure the first works? If I run this in `node`, it gives `TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Also throws the same exception in Chrome, FireFox, IE11...

Comment: Guys, im sorry. I had inadvertently pasted wrong code. sdata = [] should be sdata = [[]].

Comment: @TarunSSandhu I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

> Which means I cannot just create an empty array and give values to it. I have to count how many rows will it be, and then initialize an empty array of that much length and then give values to its elements. Which is particularly stupid because i don't know the length of data that I am going to get.

Yes, it's stupid. It's stupid because computers are stupid. Deal with it. Lots of people have solved this problem before you, of course.

One way to solve it is to **force the user to give you JSON.** That's really easy. Now instead of trying to write

```js
var sdata = [[]];
sdata[0][0] = 4;
sdata[0][1] = 5;
sdata[1][0] = 6;
```

you can just paste what they give you:

```js
var sdata = [[4,5],[6]];
```

This is super-easy, and you can blame the user if things go wrong.

Another thing that you can do is to look for what sorts of **data boundaries** signify a new row. For example, when parsing CSV, you look for a newline character and increment the row index, and then you append a new array onto the output text.

Finally, if you insist on writing it out, just modify the original array! You can just as easily write the following:

```js
var sdata = [];
sdata[0] = [];
sdata[0][0] = 4;
sdata[0][1] = 5;
sdata[1] = [];
sdata[1][0] = 6;
```

if you're into this whole "writing too much" shtick.

Comment: @CommuSoft Right, `node` has a good JS engine. Whatever Tarun S Sandhu is using is not one.

Answer (score 0):

Your statements:

```
var sdata = [];
sdata[0][0] = 4;
sdata[0][1] = 5;
```

should fail, and running this with `node` (node.js), it does:

```
$ node
> var sdata = [];
undefined
> sdata[0][0] = 4;
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
    at repl:1:13
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:133:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:280:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:206:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:535:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:812:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:108:10)
```

The reason is that `sdata[0]` returns `undefined`:

```
> sdata[0]
undefined
```

Now how can you add an item to `undefined` (which you can "compare" with a `null` pointer). You need at least an *object* to add items to.

You could solve the problem simply by generating some *guard* pattern:

```
function add_data (sdata,i,j,x) {
    var obj = sdata[i];
    if(obj === undefined) {
        obj = [];
        sdata[i] = obj;
    }
    obj[j] = x;
}
```

Which you could then call with:

```
var sdata = [];
add_data(sdata,0,0,4);
add_data(sdata,0,1,5);
add_data(sdata,1,0,5);
```

and will result in:

```
> sdata
[ [ 4, 5 ], [ 5 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional array doesn't really exists... 
Try this solution:

```
if ( sdata[ x ] === undefined) sdata[ x ] = [];
sdata[ x ] [ y ] = yourValue;
```